# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the following php code the while loop only runs once even if there is more than one row in practice_calendar_times.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM practice_calendar_times;
    ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if($result){
    while($practice = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //... Prints data from the row + more ...
    }
}
```

On the web page I get a printed warning message: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /rmounts/vol0-nas/yorkweb/webs/fencing/MyWebSite/homecontent.php on line 113".

Line 113 is the while loop. I looked it up and apparently this is generally caused by a syntax error with the mysql query. However this is not the case here; the mysql is correctly pulling the first row from the database and the while loop is running once. If I replace the while with an if it does not complain and prints out one row. I also tried deleting all but one row in practice_calendar_times, but still get the warning message. However when I delete all of the rows it does not print a warning.

Any ideas on how to get the while loop to iterate through the table and stop complaining?

Comment: Can you add or die ( mysql_error () ) to the line with mysql_query (before the semi-colon) and see if it is returning an error.  If it is, what is it?

Comment: Meagar, yes you are right!! The loop was quite large and I had an inner-query that I didn't even consider, which was re-assigning $result. Please post your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: If you are going to give a down arrow, please at least post the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you altering the value of `$result` in the body of the while loop? Why not change it to an `if` and `var_dump($result)` after it to make sure it's still a resource?

Answer (score 0):

you have a wild **;** in the definition of $sql

Do you get the first result correctly?

Comment: Yea I get one result from the table. I am 100% sure that it's not a fluke. Semicolon should be a valid character in an sql query.

Comment: okay, in that case could you add:
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
before the while to see if the number of rows is actually bigger than 1, if so then probably it's something inside the loop that's affecting the outcome.

Comment: The semi-colon is unrelated. This is one mighty suspicious upvote.

Comment: @meagar the semicolon was just a comment, what I wanted was to ask for info in order to give a response, at that time I still was unable to comment on questions

Answer (score -1):

try removing the semicolon in your query..
so just

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM practice_calendar_times";
```

Comment: No go. Still getting the same warning message.

Comment: The semi-colon is unrelated. This is one mighty suspicious upvote.